# Find if array of arrays contains more than 1 nan element?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to find if conf_int_arr has more than 1 [nan, nan] array, how can i do that?

```
conf_int_arr = [array([nan, nan]),
 array([39.49, 57.08]),
 array([nan, nan]),
 array([nan, nan])]
```

I searched the solution but this not works.

```
np.where(conf_int_arr != conf_int_arr.round())
```

Comment: Do you have a list of numpy arrays? or do you have a 2D numpy array?

Comment: its consist of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it but it works.

```py
import numpy as np


conf_int_arr = [
    np.array([np.nan, np.nan]),
    np.array([39.49, 57.08]),
    np.array([np.nan, np.nan]),
    np.array([np.nan, np.nan]),
]
nan_array = np.array([np.nan, np.nan])
print(np.sum([np.array_equal(each_array, nan_array, equal_nan=True) for each_array in conf_int_arr]))
```

Comment: I got this error array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list

Comment: Please check out the updated solution

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert your list to a numpy array and then count the rows which only contain nan values:

```
import numpy as np

conf_int_arr = [np.array([np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([39.49, 57.08]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan])]

conf_int_arr = np.array(conf_int_arr)
result = np.isnan(conf_int_arr).all(axis=1).sum()

print(result)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: I got this error array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list

Comment: Should work now.